# Problem muting the output of Gurobi in Julia (using JuMP)

Tags: optimization, julia, gurobi, julia-jump

I am using `Gurobi` through `JuMP` and I have been having trouble silencing the output of the optimizer.

While the statements:

```
set_silent(model)
set_optimizer_attribute(model, "OutputFlag", 0)
```

mute some of the output, it still outputs the message:

```
Set parameter Username
Academic license - for non-commercial use only - expires yyyy-mm-dd
```

I am using the `Gurobi` optimizer in a loop, so this is printed multiple times. I have not been able to find a solution to this yet online. Does anybody have an answer to it?

Thank you for your time,
ckolomv

Comment: I believe it is not possible unless you use some hacks to redirect all of the the standard output of the process. But usually this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to silence it. This is an explicit choice made by the Gurobi developers.

You can print only once by re-using the environment:

```
using JuMP, Gurobi
const env = Gurobi.Env()
for _ in 1:10
    model = Model(() -> Gurobi.Optimizer(env))
end
```

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for the response. Should I paste this in the functions that are using Gurobi? Or the "main" script? I am still new to Julia.

Comment: You should edit the code to put your stuff inside the for loop.